# Google App Engine instance shuts down and starts repeatedly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

#### Premise / What you want to achieve

I am creating a web application with Python Flask in the Google App Engine standard environment, and I want to set app.yaml as follows so that one instance is always running.

```
[app.yaml]
runtime: python37

instance_class: F2

inbound_services:
- warmup

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT --workers 2 --threads 2 main:app

automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 1
  max_instances: 2
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
```

#### What is happening and what you want to check

**If you leave it for a while without any access** and check the log,
You can see that the instance is repeatedly shut down and started as shown below.
(It is often repeated several times an hour.)

```
/_ah/warmup
[INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (7)
[INFO] Using worker: threads
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18
[INFO] Handling signal: term
[INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15)
[INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18)
[INFO] Shutting down: Master
/_ah/warmup
[INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (7)
[INFO] Using worker: threads
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17
```

Since min_instances is set, set a warm-up request and set it.
You can also see from the log that the application is processing.
Since it starts immediately by the warm-up request, the result is that one instance is always started, but in this way, it is correct behavior that **the instance shuts down and starts repeatedly without any access.** Is not it?

#### Supplementary information

The following sample app is for questions.

```
[requirements.txt]
Flask==1.1.1
gunicorn
```

```
[main.py]
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/_ah/warmup')
def warmup():
    # Handle your warmup logic here, e.g. set up a database connection pool
    return '', 200, {}
```

Comment: Your instance is being terminated. Probably because your application is not listening on port 8080. Why are you listening on port 8081? The default is 8080. I see nothing in your question where you changed the default port number. Do you logs have date and time? What is the time interval from `Starting gunicorn 20.0.4` to receiving `Handling signal: term`?

Comment: You did not explicitly specify port 8081. I just wrote it in the entrypoint of app.yaml, as it was in the App Engine documentation. By the way, you can always access the web application even in this state. The time interval between starting gunicorn 20.0.4 and receiving the Handling signal: term is not always constant. It can be from a few minutes to a few tens of minutes, or even a few hours. I'm wondering if it's the right thing for an instance to shut down and start up many times.

Comment: Where are you specifying the handler for `warmup`?

Comment: You say that it shuts down several times an hour so it sounds like you app is working to some extent.  My guess is that you are exceeding memory limits and this causes the shutdown.  Try increasing instance memory.

Comment: The warmup handler is specified by @app.route('/_ah /warmup') in main.py as described in the Google documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuring-warmup-requests

Comment: It was possible to exceed the memory limit with the original web application, but it is difficult to think that the memory limit has been exceeded with the sample application described above, and the cause is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Yes.

There's nothing wrong with the sample application provided. The warmup path is correctly configured as per the documentation and the app.yaml settings are okay. Also, this doesn't seem to be an out of memory scenario since you would see such event reflected in the logs and the monitoring graphs visible in App Engine UI.

Keep in mind that App Engine is a managed service that scales on demand using a variety of heuristics based on application metrics such as memory consumption among others. While the **min_instances** settings determines that an instance ought to be running at all times there are a variety of reasons that could cause a particular instance to shutdown. The key point here is that, regardless of a particular instance shutting down or spawning, the settings defined in the app.yaml will be respected. Note this fact is reflected in the attached logs, there's always an instance active. Overall, graceful terminations are to be expected in this kind of managed environments and won't have an impact in your applications availability.